# Available Live Helper Chat RESTAPI's and the parameters to be passed

Tags: api, chat, helper, live

I want to use few of the API's built by Live Helper chat.
To be specific, 
  1.I want to get all the chats within a specified date range.
  2. The chat objects i get in response are limited to 20 in number.How can I increase the limit?.
I tried to go throught their [Documentation](https://livehelperchat.com/documentation-6c.html) , but it was not helpful at all.
I will be greatful if somebody can answer my question.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but just in case someone else is stuck on this.

Took me a while to figure out but i thinks its a bug in the api where it wont acknowledge 'limit' as a filter when fetching chat records.

Here's what i did.

(1)
open lib\core\lhrestapi\lhrestapivalidator.php

(2) Find the function 'public static function validateChatList()'

(3)
Add this to the end of $validAttributes

```
'limit' => array(
    'type' => 'general',
    'field' => 'limit',
    'validator' => new 
ezcInputFormDefinitionElement(ezcInputFormDefinitionElement::OPTIONAL, 
'int', array(
        'min_range' => 1
    ))
)
```

(4) Now you can add 'limit' to the params of your api call and the it will return upto that many records. Eg limit=100